# How to create vertical slider with Swiper Vue.js?

Tags: slider, swiper.js, vuejs3

I am creating simple app using Vue3, also I am using Swiprer.js for vue,  documentation of swiper.js (for vue3) is  incomprehensible to me, I have imported all modules in my application, but now i want to create vertical scrollable slider, like picture below, my swiper component looks like this:
[image]

but still can't create vertical scrollable slider, this what my template looks like, any solutions?

```html
<template>
  <div class="container-main-slider">
    <div class="container-main-slider__inner" id="sliderBox">
      <swiper
        :slides-per-view="1"
        :space-between="20"
        :direction="vertical"
        :pagination="{ clickable: true}"
      >
        <swiper-slide>
          <img :src="dynamic content">
        </swiper-slide> 
      </swiper>
    </div>
  </div>



</template>



<script>
/* swiper slider imports */
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/vue";
import SwiperCore, { A11y, Autoplay, Pagination } from "swiper";
import "swiper/swiper.scss";
import "swiper/swiper.scss";
import 'swiper/components/pagination/pagination.scss';
SwiperCore.use([A11y, Autoplay,Pagination]);
export default {

  data(){
   return{
     fixedheader:false,
   }
  },
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
  },

  methods:{
    showVideo(){
       this.$store.commit("CheckvideoVisibility", false)
    },
    onSlideChange() {
        console.log('slide change');
      },
  },
   
  
};
</script>
```

`
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution
If someone faced the same problem: you just need to put 'vertical' in single quotes.
It will look like this in Vue template:

```
<swiper 
  :slides-per-view="1"     
  :space-between="0"
  :direction="'vertical'"
>
```